# CSS How to make a div container show background images to the left and right outside of the div?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

The website I'm developing uses the bootstrap framework. The problem that follows is that I have a container div that should have a background image outside the div both to the left and to the right with the chosen image background. Below are examples of what I intend. Someone can help me? Thank you.

HTML/PHP

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="container fundo" id="fadein1">
  <br>
  <br>
  <a href="admin_bairro_adicionar.php" class="btn btn-success">Nova Publicação</a>
  <br>
  <br>
  <p class="titulo_grande">Bairro Mineiro</p>
  <div class="row">
    <?php
            $select_stmt=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM bairro ORDER BY id DESC;"); //sql select query
            $select_stmt->execute();
            while($row=$select_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
            ?>
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <a class="linha_paginas"></a>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div id="titulo_titulo">
          <?php echo $row['titulo'];?>
        </div>
        <br>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <a class="fancybox" href="upload/bairro/<?php echo $row['image']; ?>" data-fancybox-group="media-gallery"><img src="upload/bairro/<?php echo $row['image']; ?>" id="imagem" class="imagem img-fluid"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div id="texto_texto">
          <?php echo $row['texto'];?>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6" align="right"><a href="admin_bairro_editar.php?update_id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-warning">Editar</a></div>
      <div class="col-sm-6"><a href="?delete_id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</a></div>
      <?php
            }
        ?>
        <br>
        <br>

  </div>
</div>
```

[image: sketch]

Comment: which version of boostrap is this about ? (for the tag)

Comment: The version is Bootstrap 4.0

Comment: okay, why can you not use body for the bg ?

Comment: beside using a wrapper or body, absolute pseudos work too  https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/dEvYrL

Answer (score 0):

in this case you have to put your fundo container inside another container-fluid, so:

```
   <div class="container-fluid back-img">
    <div class="container fundo" id="fadein1">
        <br>
        <br>
        <a href="admin_bairro_adicionar.php" class="btn btn-success">Nova Publicação</a>
        <br>
        <br>
        <p class="titulo_grande">Bairro Mineiro</p>
        <div class="row">
        <?php
            $select_stmt=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM bairro ORDER BY id DESC;");    //sql select query
            $select_stmt->execute();
            while($row=$select_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
            ?>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <a class="linha_paginas"></a>
                <br>
                <br>
                <div id="titulo_titulo"><?php echo $row['titulo'];?></div>
                <br>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <a class="fancybox" href="upload/bairro/<?php echo $row['image']; ?>" data-fancybox-group="media-gallery"><img src="upload/bairro/<?php echo $row['image']; ?>" id="imagem" class="imagem img-fluid"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <div id="texto_texto"><?php echo $row['texto'];?></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6" align="right"><a href="admin_bairro_editar.php?update_id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-warning" >Editar</a></div>
            <div class="col-sm-6"><a href="?delete_id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-danger" >Eliminar</a></div>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
        <br>
        <br>

    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

now on css, you add a background img to the container-fluid div that i gave the class name back-img,and use the following code:

```
.back-img{
background-img: url("your url");
}
```

you can also use body instead,but it's better to use a div if you don't want the background image on the whole page.
i hope this will help you

**update:** if you want background image in each side alone, you should change your container to container-fluid, and add 3 cols like that:

```
<div class="col-sm-2 background-left"> </div>
<div class="col-sm-8 center"> // your mane block should be here(buttons and all your elements </div>
<div class="col-sm-2 background-right"> </div>
```

and now you add the css code

```
.background-left{
background-img: url("your url");
}

.background-right{
background-img: url("your url");
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: The `container-fluid` class is not necessary though, a simple `div` with the `back-img` class is enough, a block-level element will use the full available width anyways

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do this by wrapping another DIV around container and applying background to that doc, instead.

```
<div class=“body-bg”>
     <div class=“container”>
            ....
     </div>
</div>
```

Now, in your CSS, you write this:

```
.body-bg {
     background: url(‘path-to-your-image.jpg’);
     width: 100vw; /* you shouldn’t need this as DIVs usually take width or parent container, anyway */ 
}
```